# What code do you use to generate the text to go into the HTML title tag?

Tags: title, templates, headers

The question title says it all. Myself I just stick with the default code from one of the packaged templates that comes with WordPress out of the box:

```
<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
```

Do any of you use different code for this?

Comment: While it is interesting how people handle this, common (and more practical answer, what if you change theme?) would be using some SEO plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Mine is:

```
  function getDocumentTitle($separator = " &laquo; "){

    $title = get_bloginfo('name');
    $desc = get_bloginfo('description');

    if(is_front_page() && is_home() && !empty($desc)){
      $title .= $separator.$desc;

    }elseif(is_home() || is_singular()){
      $id = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get_queried_object_id();
      if($meta = get_post_meta($id, 'title', true)) $title .= $separator.$meta;
      $title .= (empty($meta) && is_front_page() && !empty($desc)) ? $separator.$desc : $separator.get_post_field('post_title', $id);

    }elseif(is_archive()){    
      if(is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax()){
        $term = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get_queried_object();
        $title .= $separator.$term->name;

      }elseif(is_author()){
        $title .= $separator.get_the_author_meta('display_name', get_query_var('author'));

      }elseif(is_date()){
        if(is_day())
          $title .= $separator.sprintf(_a('Archive for %s'), get_the_time(apply_filters('doc_title_archive_day_format', 'F jS, Y')));
        elseif(get_query_var('w'))
          $title .= $separator.$separator.sprintf(_a('Archive for week %1$s of %2$s'), get_the_time('W'), get_the_time('Y'));

        elseif(is_month())
          $title .= $separator.sprintf(_a('Archive for %s'), single_month_title(' ', false));
        elseif(is_year())
          $title .= $separator.sprintf(_a('Archive for year %s'), get_the_time('Y'));

      }else{
        $title .= $separator.post_type_archive_title('', false);

      }

    }elseif(is_search()){
      $title .= $separator.sprintf(_a('Search results for %s'), '&quot;'.get_search_query().'&quot;');

    }elseif(is_404()){
      $title .= $separator._a('404 Not Found');

    }

    // paged?
    if((($page = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get('paged')) || ($page = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get('page'))) && $page > 1 && !is_404())
      $title .= $separator.sprintf(_a('Page %s'), $page);

    // comment page?
    if(get_query_var('cpage'))
      $title .= $separator.sprintf(_a('Comment Page %s'), get_query_var('cpage'));

    // apply the wp_title filters so we're compatible with plugins
    return apply_filters('wp_title', $title, $separator, '');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :: '; } ?><?php  bloginfo('name'); if(is_home()) { echo ' :: '; bloginfo('description'); } ?></title>
```

http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/ultimate-guide-to-wordpress-seo-optimized-titles/

Works for me :)

I try to avoid plugins where possible.